# npx create-react-app is not working despite trying the following that i have described below

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, react-scripts

```
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          node_modules/react-scripts

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

initially i was getting this then after sunning `npm audit fix --force` i got this error

```
A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again.
```

At this point i see  react-script is saved in devDependencies with version 5.0.1
so i move it back to Dependencies and try `npm i`

i got the `6 high severity vulnerabilities` again

i tried npm audit fix --force
several times